# random variables and infinite sequence

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

If  $\{x_n\}$ is infinite sequence of **random variables** and all $\{x_n\}$  values are **positive** and **real numbers**
 then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is random variable too

Anyone can guide me for this question? Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know by definition, a random variable $X$ is just a measurable function defined on a probability space. So it suffices to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ is a measurable function.

We know from measure theory, if $f_n$ be measurable function for all $n$, then their pointwise limit (if exists in extended real number, which means we allow the limit be $\infty$) is also a measurable function. Note, since $X_n\ge 0$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n(\omega)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N X_n(\omega)$ converges for all $\omega$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^N X_n$ is measurable (addition of two measurable functions is measurable), hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ is measurable.

Comment: Thank you , what if we just knew that ${x_{n}}$ values were just real numbers and we had no information if they were positive

Comment: @ArekCastiel Then we can't guarantee the series is convergent. In other words, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ may not be well defined. So we can't say anything.